# Wait for getJSON response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, getjson, yql

i'm trying to make a script using Yahoo's **YQL** in a web applicaion. The script looks over a text paragraph and then it finds some references and appends on the text as a popup. It all goes fine until I have to loop through each reference with class "verso", after getting my response it appends all the references in the last element of the list.

Here is the javascript code (rewrited and simplified)

```
            var url="";
            var version = "RVR1960";
            var verso = "";

            $("div.post-body").find(".verso").each(function(i){
                $resultado = null;
                verso = $(this).text();
                url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?" + "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
                    encodeURIComponent("http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=" + verso +
                    "&version=" + version) + "%22&format=xml'&callback=?";
                $pasaje = $(this);

                $.getJSON(url,function(data){
                    if(data.results[0])
                    {
                        $resultado = null;
                        $resultado = $(data.results[0]).find("div.result-text-style-normal:first");
                        $resultado.find("h5, div, a").remove();
                        $("<div class='cita'><span class='left'>&ldquo;</span>"+
                            $resultado.html()+
                            "<p align='right'><b>"+verso+"</b></p>"+
                            "<span class='right'>&rdquo;</span></div>").appendTo($pasaje);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $resultado = $("<p>Pasaje no encontrado.</p>");
                    }
                });
            });
```

and here is my html:

```
<div class="post-body"><b class="verso">Juan 3:16</b><b class="verso">Mateo 11:28</b><b class="verso">Juan 1:1</b></div>
```

I'll appreciate all the help

Comment: what is your expected result, and what is actually happening?

Comment: I expect the script to append each reference to each element with class "verse" respectively. Instead of that i'm getting that it appends all in the LAST element of my each loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so, I have change several things in your code, now it works, have fun;)

```
var url="";
var version = "RVR1960";
var verso = "";

$("div.post-body > b.verso").each(function(i){
    resultado = null;
    verso = $(this).text();
    url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+"q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+encodeURIComponent("http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search="+verso+"&version="+version)+"%22&format=xml'&callback=?";

    $.getJSON(url,function(data){
        if(data.results[0])
        {
            resultado = null;
            resultado = $(data.results[0]).find("div.result-text-style-normal:first");
            resultado.find("h5, div, a").remove();
            $("<div class='cita'><span class='left'>&ldquo;</span>"+resultado.html()+"<p align='right'><b>"+verso+"</b></p>"+"<span class='right'>&rdquo;</span></div>").appendTo($("div.post-body > b.verso")[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            resultado = $("<p>Pasaje no encontrado.</p>");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I came to that answer too, and resolved some other problems, thanks a lot.